# Check for resultCode in Android's BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want to make a check if `resultCode` is `RESULT_OK` in Android's `BroadcastReceiver`'s `onReceive` method like we do in `onActivityResult` method of an Activity, but how will I do that is my question.

**Receiver's code is:**

```
new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //This is what I like to check.
                //if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To make a check of **resultCode** in BroadcastReceiver's onReceive(...) method, we can use  `getResultCode()` method of **[BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#getResultCode%28%29)**. 
This will give us current **[resultCode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29)** (which can be the standard results

- **RESULT_CANCELED**,
- **RESULT_OK**

or any custom values starting at **RESULT_FIRST_USER**).

**For the above question, its implementation is given as:**

```
new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //This is what I like to check.
                if(getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                {
                     //Your code here.
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 4):

You can used following code

```
if (getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK ) {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

by default you can not override onactivityResult method in Broadcast receiver but you can do it in following way :

1. override onactivityResult method in any activty subclass
2. storing result into sharedpreference
3. access that value from onreceive method of broadcast using
   context

or initialize this type of global variable .
and after compare with it.

```
private int resultCancel = Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;
private int resultOk = Activity.RESULT_OK;
```

Comment: You misinterpreted, I want to check for resultCode, not to implement onActivityResult in onReceive method.

Comment: @Hoosier i added more information , this must be useful for you.

Comment: from where this resultOK come to compare with Activity.RESULT_OK, that is my question.

Comment: please you can briefly explain me what you are trying to do so i can exactly help you? because as per my knowledge my friend you can not use directly RESULT_OK int value into broadcast receiver subclass.

Comment: if for any broadcast, I can check RESULT_OK then that would be good. But the question is from where I will get resultCode in onReceive to which I will compare with RESULT_OK.

Comment: do you know what is shared preference?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48150/discussion-between-nil-and-hoosier)

Comment: Hi nil, I found it. We can do it using getResultCode() method; which returns resultCode to which you can compare with Activity.RESULT_OK.